# Почему получаю ошибку при переключении BuildVariant?

Tags: android, build

Вот так выглядит мой `buildTypes` в `build.gradle` (app)

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_DEBUG_MODE", "false"
    }
    debug{
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_DEBUG_MODE", "false"
    }
    debugWithTrueDebugMode {
        initWith debug
        buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_DEBUG_MODE", "true"
    }
}
```

Когда активен `release` или `debug` все хорошо

Когда переключаюсь на `debugWithTrueDebugMode`

то получаю ошибку

```
C:\LocalGit\Supergas\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\
debugWithTrueDebugMode\AndroidManifest.xml
Error:(59) error: resource string/google_maps_key (aka 
com.ewavemobile.supergas:string/google_maps_key) not found.
Error:(59) resource string/google_maps_key (aka 
com.ewavemobile.supergas:string/google_maps_key) not found.
Error:failed processing manifest.
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for 
details
Error:Execution failed for task 
':app:processDebugWithTrueDebugModeResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt
```

Нашел несколько похожих проблем, советуют поменять buildToolsVersion '26.0.2' на более низкую. Но я не могу, минимальная версия `gradle plugin 3.0.1` поддерживает версии билд тула 26.0.+

Что делать?

**Правка**

Добавил под `<application>` в манифесте вот это

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Но не помогло...

Comment: `Error:(59) error: resource string/google_maps_key (string/google_maps_key) not found.`, попробуйте вручную задать в манифесте ключ апи Google maps

Comment: @Iman Добавил в вопрос дополнение насчет этого

Comment: Скорее всего это связано с тем, что вы используете нестандартный buildType. Вместо этого используйте product flavours

Comment: @httpdispatch не, я так не думаю... в другом проекте этот подход отлично работает. С flavors это немного другой подход

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko после последних обновлений Gradle, он пытается брать ресурсы из соответствующего buildVariant всех зависимостей. Если такой buildVariant отсутствует в библиотеке, то теоретически это может быть причиной.

Comment: @httpdispatch Да но , что мне не нравится при таком подходе это то, что соответствующий `flavor` добавится во все `build variants` и второе это то , что мне эту переменную нужно вытаскивать в отдельный файл. Так ведь? Или в новом градл это по другому работает?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Зачем вам вообще этот велосипед? Используйте flavors как это делают другие. Вот пример от JakeWharton есть внутренний и production билд
https://github.com/JakeWharton/u2020

Comment: Кстати, а где лежит strings.xml в котором находится константа google_maps_key?

Comment: @httpdispatch  Да точно! проверил, действительно этот проект был перенесен с эклипс на андроид и теперь там немного кривовато построена архитектура и эта переменная лежит только под `debug` в общем перенес ее в стринг файл там где она должна быть и все работает. Закиньте ответ отмечу как правильный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятнее всего константа google_maps_key лежит в файле, который не видим в режиме `debugWithTrueDebugMode`.

Эта переменная лежит в файле который находится под директорией `release` или `debug` (`app->debug->res->values->string.xml`) а когда вы находитесь в режиме `debugWithTrueDebugMode` , то студия пытается взять ее отсюда `app->debugWithTrueDebugMode->res->values->string.xml`.

Но так как этой переменной нет под этой директорией, то получаете ошибку.

Что нужно сделать

1) Создать `string.xml` который виден всем `app->res->values->string.xml`
2) Поместить эту переменную в файл `string.xml` под нужную директорию (В вашем случае `app->debugWithTrueDebugMode->res->values->string.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676848/android-string-resource-not-found
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31516669/android-string-resource-not-found-while-trying-to-get-resource-in-list-activit

На крайняк понизь версию gradle plugin 3.0.1.

Comment: Первые ссылки не совсем то что мне нужно. У меня нет проблемы с R импортом или еще что то , я так понимаю, что проблема в том, что приложение пытается получить этот ключ в рантайме , а он по какой то причине при конфигурации `buildWithDebugModeTrue` не содержиться... Насчет понижения версии, тоже не помагает

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Может добавить minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro' в секцию debugWithTrueDebugMode { ???

Comment: Не... Не помагает

Answer (score 0):

Решение @httpdispatch частично помогло. Нужно найти файл google_maps_api.xml и положить его по аналогичному пути в app\src\release\res\values\google_maps_api.xml. Тот же ключ заработает и для release-версии, если не применено ограничений ключа. Если же они применены (на сайте консоли Google), то надо создать новый ключ для release.